# ajaxStart / ajaxStop / load Optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, optimization

I'm trying to optimize my Ajax code — it's slow and isn't working smoothly.

**#first** DIV is a logo 
**#second** DIV is a loader

I want to replace my **logo** with a **loader** while the script is doing Ajax-requests.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        $('#first').hide();
        $('#second').show();
    }).ajaxStop(function(){
        $('#second').hide();
        $('#first').show();
    });

    //Several database requests via .load(), .click(), $(document).on("click") etc. here
    //Everytime I call them, I want this replacement to be done quickly.

});
```

Should I preload logo/loader?

Comment: I am not sure there is a way to optimize this, Ajax starts, UI element is hidden, and another is shown, AjaxStops and these elements are toggled. You are using jQuery, client side the dom elements are manipulated, the only thing you can do is reduce work done before ajaxStart is called, if there is any code even doing anything before you make an ajax call

Comment: You have already "preloaded" the logo and loader when the page is loaded, both the DOM elements exist in the HTML. You can't get any faster than show and hide with an existing DOM HTML element with style="display:none;"

Comment: you could try a jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut to make a smoother transition

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm also interested, if ajaxStart/ajaxStop is placed correctly - before other methods which load content from database.

Comment: I don't think you can place it incorrectly, you got it in a document.ready so as long as it is part of the javascript stack on page load, you can't get that any faster, it fires whenever there is an Ajax call so really doesn't matter when you load ajaxStop and ajaxStart events as long as it is before you call Ajax

Comment: i would make it so that if ajax calls overlap, the closing first one won't hide the indicator before the 2nd one is done.